# Python, range()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been learning about parallel lists. This is a code, where we ask a user: how many people does he want to use, what names they have and about age. Then, we want to access a concrete item of the list by entering his/her index. [python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0ldi.png)I have a problem in understanding why do we use range(sumOfNumbers)? As we iterate through all the items of the lists, range(stop) doesn't include the last element, only exclude it. So why do we use range(sumOfNumbers), if we need to iterate over all the items?

Comment: Please paste your code instead of a link to a screenshot of it.  Images aren't searchable or accessible and they make it impossible to include your original code in an answer.

Comment: Keep in mind, that Python indices start counting at 0, not 1.

Comment: Generally, you *don't* iterate over the range; you iterate over the list itself. Prefer `for x in some_list: # use x` to `for i in range(len(x)): # use some_list[i]`.

Comment: To iterate over a list, you should look at `enumerate()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that `range(n)` goes from 0 to n-1, but so do indices. The first element of a list of n items is at index 0, and the last is at n-1.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are referring to the fact that

```
range(n)
```

is the range of numbers

```
0, 1, ..., n-1
```

which is also the range of indices of a list containing **n** elements.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is that when we count things in code, we usually start at 0, not 1.  So if you want to count 4 things, then you count 0, 1, 2, 3 -- if `range` ended at 4, you'd have an extra item!